# How to handle concurrent dataimports in DataImportHandler?

Tags: multithreading, solr, concurrency, dataimporthandler

Can somebody please explain how DIH handles concurrency?

I have setup a MySql JDBC datasource and need to do some custom processing of the data imported by sending a field value to a Apache Stanbol enhancement server. I'm doing this by configuring a custom EventListener at the end of the dataimport (onImportEnd).

During the dataimport process I'm copying the field value of each document to a static Map in my StanbolEventListener and onImportEnd I'm sending them to Stanbol for enhancement.

I need to handle concurrency in this process. Need to make my Map thread-safe. For that I need to get an idea of how concurrency is handled in DIH.

For testing purpose I issued a /dataimport for docs 0-100 and while the request was processing issued another request for docs 101-200. I got below exception in the log. Can someone please explain how to handle my data concurrency in the DIH?;

```
    [Thread-15] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource  – Ignoring Error when closing connection
java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@1e820764 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:3314)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2477)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollbackNoChecks(ConnectionImpl.java:5165)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:5048)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4654)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1630)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.closeConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:410)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.close(JdbcDataSource.java:395)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.closeEntityProcessorWrappers(DocBuilder.java:284)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:422)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:487)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:468)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dileepa

There use to be a multi-threading feature for DIH,  but it was removed since SOLR 4.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3262

Comment: thanks leoh, it seems DIH doesn't support this inherently anymore. I tackled the problem by implementing a consumer-producer Queue data model for my concurrent data.